# How do I link a file on my computer with an item in Visual Studio using Sitecore Rocks, without the use of IIS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-rocks

I am a programmer working for a university. I'm trying to add a .aspx page (written in .NET/C#) to a folder that I have access to in the university's Sitecore. From what I understand, that means I need to link the .NET file to a Sitecore item, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I have looked at the Sitecore Rocks tutorials out there by [John West](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/09/Create-a-Visual-Studio-2010-Project-for-a-Sitecore-Solution.aspx), Trevor Campbell, [Sean Kearney](http://seankearney.com/post/Visual-Studio-Projects-and-Sitecore.aspx) and others and I couldn't find any tutorials that left the Location field BLANK in the Connection window (the one that says "Optional - specify only if you have physical access" beneath it). All the ones I've seen specify a Location on their computer, indicating that they have local access.

The part of my university's Sitecore that I'm trying to add to is hosted (on Rackspace), so it's not on my computer. I can add the connection (leaving the Location field blank). I can connect my visual studio project (with the .aspx in it) to the Sitecore connection. I can even use "Sitecore>Bind File to Item..." in the context menu of the file to bind it to an existing Sitecore item, but that doesn't seem to help me at all, because it still doesn't create an item in Sitecore that I can edit in Visual Studio.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add a Sitecore sublayout item and related ascx file using the regular Visual Studio 'Add -> New Item' option.
This is detailed here:-
http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Trevor-Campbell/Posts/2013/02/28-Days-of-Sitecore-Rocks-Layouts-and-Sublayouts.aspx

The 'Bind File to Item' just means that there's added context menu option on the ascx file to edit the Related Sitecore item directly.
There's also an extra context menu option on the Sitecore Explorer side to edit the related ascx file directly.

This relationship is the same one that's created with the above 'Add' option in Visual Studio.

If this doesn't work, I'd say that this functionality requires the Hard Rock WebService to be installed, which can only be added if you have physical access to the site.

Comment: Thanks, Sean! I'll see if someone with server access can get it updated to Hard Rock Web Service.